Keep a running average of upload/download speeds in python
I'm currently trying to adapt a script that shows network stats like upload and download speeds for each process we can detect using a network; the original script is described here (https://thepythoncode.com/article/make-a-network-usage-monitor-in-python),
and my version is as follows:
from scapy.all import *
import psutil
from collections import defaultdict
import os
from threading import Thread
import pandas as pd




# get the all network adapter's MAC addresses
all_macs = {iface.mac for iface in ifaces.values()}
# A dictionary to map each connection to its correponding process ID (PID)
connection2pid = {}
# A dictionary to map each process ID (PID) to total Upload (0) and Download (1) traffic
pid2traffic = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
# the global Pandas DataFrame that's used to track previous traffic stats
global_df = None
# global boolean for status of the program
is_program_running = True

def get_size(bytes):
    """
    Returns size of bytes in a nice format
    """
    for unit in ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P']:
        if bytes < 1024:
            return f"{bytes:.2f}{unit}B"
        bytes /= 1024


def process_packet(packet):
    global pid2traffic
    try:
        # get the packet source & destination IP addresses and ports
        packet_connection = (packet.sport, packet.dport)
    except (AttributeError, IndexError):
        # sometimes the packet does not have TCP/UDP layers, we just ignore these packets
        pass
    else:
        # get the PID responsible for this connection from our `connection2pid` global dictionary
        packet_pid = connection2pid.get(packet_connection)
        if packet_pid:
            if packet.src in all_macs:
                # the source MAC address of the packet is our MAC address
                # so it's an outgoing packet, meaning it's upload
                pid2traffic[packet_pid][0] += len(packet)
            else:
                # incoming packet, download
                pid2traffic[packet_pid][1] += len(packet)


def get_connections():
    """A function that keeps listening for connections on this machine 
    and adds them to `connection2pid` global variable"""
    global connection2pid
    while is_program_running:
        # using psutil, we can grab each connection's source and destination ports
        # and their process ID
        for c in psutil.net_connections():
            if c.laddr and c.raddr and c.pid:
                # if local address, remote address and PID are in the connection
                # add them to our global dictionary
                connection2pid[(c.laddr.port, c.raddr.port)] = c.pid
                connection2pid[(c.raddr.port, c.laddr.port)] = c.pid
        # sleep for a second, feel free to adjust this
        time.sleep(1)

        
def print_pid2traffic(process_start_time):
    global global_df
    # initialize the list of processes
    processes = []
    for pid, traffic in pid2traffic.items():
        # `pid` is an integer that represents the process ID
        # `traffic` is a list of two values: total Upload and Download size in bytes
        try:
            # get the process object from psutil
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            # if process is not found, simply continue to the next PID for now
            continue
        # get the name of the process, such as chrome.exe, etc.
        name = p.name()
        # get the time the process was spawned
        try:
            create_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time())
        except OSError:
            # system processes, using boot time instead
            create_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(psutil.boot_time())
        # construct our dictionary that stores process info
        
        process = {
            "pid": pid, 
            "name": name, 
            #"create_time": create_time,
            "running_time": datetime.now() - create_time,
            "process_runtime": int(timedelta.total_seconds(datetime.now() - process_start_time)),
            "Upload": traffic[0],
            "Download": traffic[1],
            "Download Speeds List": list(),
        }
        try:
            # calculate the upload and download speeds by simply subtracting the old stats from the new stats
            process["Upload Speed"] = traffic[0] - global_df.at[pid, "Upload"]
            process["Download Speed"] = traffic[1] - global_df.at[pid, "Download"]
            process["Download Speeds List"].append(global_df.at[pid, "Download Speed"])
            process["Avg Download Speed"] = sum(global_df.at[pid, "Download Speeds List"]) / global_df.at[pid, "process_runtime"]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            # If it's the first time running this function, then the speed is the current traffic
            # You can think of it as if old traffic is 0
            process["Upload Speed"] = traffic[0]
            process["Download Speed"] = traffic[1]
        # append the process to our processes list
        processes.append(process)
    # construct our Pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(processes)
    try:
        # set the PID as the index of the dataframe
        df = df.set_index("pid")
        # sort by column, feel free to edit this column
        df.sort_values("Download", inplace=True, ascending=False)
    except KeyError as e:
        # when dataframe is empty
        pass
    # make another copy of the dataframe just for fancy printing
    printing_df = df.copy()
    try:
        # apply the function get_size to scale the stats like '532.6KB/s', etc.
        printing_df["Download"] = printing_df["Download"].apply(get_size)
        printing_df["Upload"] = printing_df["Upload"].apply(get_size)
        printing_df["Download Speed"] = printing_df["Download Speed"].apply(get_size).apply(lambda s: f"{s}/s")
        printing_df["Upload Speed"] = printing_df["Upload Speed"].apply(get_size).apply(lambda s: f"{s}/s")
    except KeyError as e:
        # when dataframe is empty again
        pass
    # clear the screen based on your OS
    os.system("cls") if "nt" in os.name else os.system("clear")
    # print our dataframe
    print(printing_df.to_string())
    # update the global df to our dataframe
    global_df = df
    
    
def print_stats():
    """Simple function that keeps printing the stats"""
    process_start_time = datetime.now()

    while is_program_running:
        time.sleep(1)
        print_pid2traffic(process_start_time)
        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start the printing thread
    printing_thread = Thread(target=print_stats)
    printing_thread.start()
    # start the get_connections() function to update the current connections of this machine
    connections_thread = Thread(target=get_connections)
    connections_thread.start()
    # start sniffing
    print("Started sniffing")
    sniff(prn=process_packet, store=False)
    # setting the global variable to False to exit the program
    is_program_running = False    
    

It's wrong, but I can't yet figure out how I should fix it.
My guess is that I'm re-creating an empty list for each process every time print_pid2traffic is called, and so speed values don't really get recorded there.
